# Unsuccessful installation of libgfortran3 on Ubuntu13.10

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-13.10

I need some help on installing `libgfortran3` on an old machine that runs Ubuntu 13.10.

Here's the error message from `sudo apt-get install libgfortran3`

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:                                                 
 libgfortran3 : Depends: gcc-4.8-base (= 4.8.1-10ubuntu8) but 4.8.1-10ubuntu9 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Apparently my installed gcc-4.8-base is newer than the required version.

```
gcc-4.8-base:                                                               
  Installed: 4.8.1-10ubuntu9                                                
  Candidate: 4.8.1-10ubuntu9                                                
  Version table:                                                            
 *** 4.8.1-10ubuntu9 0                                                      
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status                                            
     4.8.1-10ubuntu8 0                                                      
        500 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/main amd64 Packages
```

Any pointers on how to resolve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: This question is about software installation on Ubuntu, not programming. (The fact it happens to be a programming library is irrelevant - questions about using the library once it's installed would be appropriate here.) This post is more suited for [ubuntu.se] instead.

Comment: @KenWhite That makes sense. Actually just found a solution to this problem by installing the package manually on the [ubuntu site](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/saucy/amd64/libgfortran3/4.8.1-10ubuntu9).